# Build Windows Electron App on M1 Mac Not Working

Tags: electron, apple-m1, electron-builder

Does anyone know if it's possible to build the electron app for Windows on an M1 Mac? I have tried and it is not working, however, I've not found or missed documentation that covers this subject.

**Issue**
The application builds correctly within the Mac, without any errors. When trying to install into a Windows machine, it does not complete and a modal appears asking to find the location of the application's shortcut.

In case I'm asked to see what packages I'm using with my application.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@tonaljs/tonal": "^4.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "electron-store": "^8.0.1",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "music-tempo": "^1.0.3",
    "node-machine-id": "^1.1.12",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vee-validate": "^3.4.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-awesome": "^4.3.1",
    "vue-custom-range-slider": "^0.2.3",
    "vue-select": "^3.11.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^16.0.7",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "electron-icon-builder": "^2.0.1",
    "electron-notarize": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? please elaborate on what you mean by "not working"

Comment: I do not get any errors during the build, but when I try and install the app on Windows computer, it does not work. It asks me to find the shortcut for the app and never loads up.

Comment: interesting, have you tried building the app directly on windows?

Comment: I have and that works, doing it now. Just prior builds with my Intel-based Mac it worked. Which I'm pretty sure is for obvious reasons. But since I'm not seeing any statement either way of support, figured I'd reach out and see if anyone else has crossed this.

Comment: I having the same issue, has anyone found a solution/workaround?

Comment: Any solution to this? It’s a major problem.